# htaccess change from index.php?cat=123&page=456&title=789 to ?p=456?

Tags: .htaccess

How do change:

> domain.nl/index.php?cat=123&page=456&title=789

to

> domain.nl/?p=456

I think I need to change .htaccess and use rewrite rules, but I can't get it to work.
I would like to use the value in variable page in the new URL. Thanks!

Comment: "can't get it to work" - what code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if index.php doesn't need the information in the cat and title variables, since you remove this information from the url. I am also assuming that index.php uses the query variable, and not the THE_REQUEST variable to get this information. You need two rules. One to externally redirect the old url to the new url. The other one needs to only work on external requests that match the url, and internally rewrites it to the old url that works.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?p=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?page=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /?p=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It is starting to work. the code after &title is now being placed behind the string. This is what WordPress puts behind it to get more readable URL's i suppose: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I'm so sorry. The comment looks awful. In short I want to get the old page-id into the new URL that gets processed by the Wordpress bit in htacces so it is a readable URL. Does that make any sense?

Comment: afaik, wordpress does all the magic in the index.php file, not in the .htaccess file, so I fear you are out-of-luck.